# Odoo get data from another model with self.env

Tags: python, database, search, odoo-8

For the Odoo warehouse module I have to do a check if all required fields have been filled when quality control wants to transfer the products to stock. 
At this moment everything works but the location for quality control is currently hardcoded. This means that when someone is using another stock location for quality control they would have to change the code.

I have searched trough the Odoo documentation and as far as I can see for the new api I have to use self.env instead of self.pool.get. (I added the old code as a comment.)
When debugging it seems that stock.warehouse is in self.pool and not in self.env (But I guess this might just be one of those "Odoo" things).

Second thing is that I have hardcoded the current company_id "1". 
I think it would be best if that could also be best if that would be a variable.

I hope someone can help me solve this.

Thanks in advance

```
class stock_transfer_details(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "stock.transfer_details"

    @api.one
    def do_detailed_transfer(self):
        res = super(stock_transfer_details, self).do_detailed_transfer()
        # Check if all the required lot additional fields have been filled.
        # Else raise warning.
        # TODO Replace hardcoded Quality location by database reference

        warehouse = self.env("stock.warehouse").search([("company_id", "=", "1")])
        # self.pool.get("stock.warehouse").browse(cr, uid, item["wh_qc_stock_loc_id"], context=context)

        qc_location = warehouse.wh_qc_stock_loc_id

        missing_mandatory_fields = []
        if self.picking_source_location_id.id == 14:
            item_ids = self.mapped("item_ids")
            for item in item_ids:
                additional_fields = item.lot_id.mapped("lot_lot_additional_fields")
                for field in additional_fields:
                    if field.lot_additional_fields.mandatory and not field.value:
                        if item.lot_id.name not in missing_mandatory_fields:
                            missing_mandatory_fields.append(item.lot_id.name)

        if missing_mandatory_fields:
            error_message = "All required fields for the serial numbers must be filled! \n"
            error_message += "Serial numbers: \n"
            for item in missing_mandatory_fields:
                error_message += item + "\n"
            raise exceptions.Warning(error_message)

        return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code:

```
for item in self.pack_move_items:
   warehouse = self.env['stock.warehouse'].browse(item.wh_qc_stock_loc_id.mapped('id'))
```

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response. I do not have the field pack_move_items, do in this case it won't work. I have also checked if this field would be available when turning on packages but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Ok! So, in your old code, you had a dictionary named `item`. Could you write here where it come from?

Comment: I am not sure where you saw the dictionary named item. The only "item" I have in this code is the one I use in for item in item_ids.

Comment: I meant this one: `self.pool.get("stock.warehouse").browse(cr, uid, item["wh_qc_stock_loc_id"], context=context)`

Comment: ah, that one. yeah, that was just something I tried but didn't work.

Comment: I have figured it out and posted the code I have used to get this to work. Thanks for your previous efforts.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I have been able to figure out how this works.

This is the code I have used to get the current warehouse quality location:

```
wh_qa_location = (self.env["stock.warehouse"].search([("partner_id.id", "=", self.create_uid.company_id.id)])).wh_qc_stock_loc_id
```

First I will look for the current warehouse the employee is in. Once that is found I will simply get the value of the wh_qc_stock_loc_id